# How to Automate Silverlight Unit Tests in Hudson?

Tags: c#, silverlight, unit-testing, hudson, automated-tests

I would like to run automated Silverlight unit tests from a Hudson build server. It seems there are two options:

- Use [Statlight](http://statlight.codeplex.com/), although it seems to be designed for TeamCity rather than Hudson, so it would involve a bit of hacking to get it to work.
- Use [NUnit Silverlight tests](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/01/nunit-and-silverlight/).

Can anyone recomend either of these options? Or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 3):

You can try using Lighthouse Silverlight Unit Test Runner, it works with every Build Server including Hudson, TeamCity and CCNet because it by default produces NUnit compatible xml results file:

http://lighthouse.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

In our company we are using NUnit with Hudson for automatized unit testing. It is simple to setup and execute.

Just download and unzip latest nunit somewhere on Hudson host.

Add Windows batch command as last buildstep with content like:

```
C:\NUnit\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe "%WORKSPACE%\src\Test\AllTests.nunit" /config=Release /xml="%WORKSPACE%\src\Test\TestResults.xml"
```

This will execute tests as defined in "AllTests.nunit" file. It is possible tu point just to one assembly (.dll).

To populate test results within Hudson Job page, you would need to install Hudson NUnit plugin. Its possible directly from Hudson plugin management.

After instalation there will be new Post build action: Publish NUnit test result report.
If you check it, you've got line to enter path to test result report. Corresponding path for example above is:

```
src/Test/TestResults.xml
```

Hope it helps you to decide ;-)

Comment: This is for normal C# .NET assemblies, but it should be same (apart from nunit-console.exe) for Silverlight. Look here: http://greenicicleblog.com/2009/12/18/running-nunit-2-53-tests-for-silverlight/ or here: http://code.google.com/p/nunit-silverlight/